Jetty set extraClasspath doesn't work after updating the jetty-maven-plugin
I've been upgrading a spring boot application to spring boot 3 (3.3.1) and so i need to upgrade the jetty version to 12 so i did. But when i try to upgrade the jetty-maven-plugin also it fails on startup.
Here is the error:
[WARNING] Failed startup of context oeje10mp.MavenWebAppContext@19105a87{/artifactId,/artifactId,b=file:///C:/Users/username/git/projectname/web-app/src/main/webapp/,a=STOPPED,h=oeje10s.SessionHandler@83b0d0f{STOPPED}}{./webapps/project-version-project.war}
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: File not resolvable or incompatible with URLClassloader: file:///C:/Users/username/git/projectname/web-app/./resources/projectArtifactId
    at org.eclipse.jetty.ee10.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.addClassPath (WebAppClassLoader.java:260)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.ee10.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.<init> (WebAppClassLoader.java:212)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.ee10.webapp.WebAppContext.configureClassLoader (WebAppContext.java:469)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.ee10.webapp.WebAppContext.preConfigure (WebAppContext.java:442)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.ee10.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart (WebAppContext.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.ee10.maven.plugin.MavenWebAppContext.doStart (MavenWebAppContext.java:311)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start (AbstractLifeCycle.java:93)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start (ContainerLifeCycle.java:169)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart (ContainerLifeCycle.java:120)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Handler$Abstract.doStart (Handler.java:491)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start (AbstractLifeCycle.java:93)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start (ContainerLifeCycle.java:169)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start (Server.java:624)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart (ContainerLifeCycle.java:120)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Handler$Abstract.doStart (Handler.java:491)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart (Server.java:565)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start (AbstractLifeCycle.java:93)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.AbstractJettyEmbedder.doStart (AbstractJettyEmbedder.java:206)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start (AbstractLifeCycle.java:93)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.ee10.maven.plugin.JettyRunMojo.startJettyEmbedded (JettyRunMojo.java:98)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.ee10.maven.plugin.AbstractWebAppMojo.startJetty (AbstractWebAppMojo.java:451)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.ee10.maven.plugin.AbstractWebAppMojo.execute (AbstractWebAppMojo.java:429)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.ee10.maven.plugin.JettyRunMojo.execute (JettyRunMojo.java:86)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:126)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute2 (MojoExecutor.java:328)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute (MojoExecutor.java:316)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:212)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:174)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.access$000 (MojoExecutor.java:75)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor$1.run (MojoExecutor.java:162)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultMojosExecutionStrategy.execute (DefaultMojosExecutionStrategy.java:39)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:159)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:73)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:53)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:118)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:261)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:173)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:906)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:283)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:206)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:568)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:283)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:226)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:407)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:348)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:47)

Here is the updated pom.xml (part of it):
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty.ee10</groupId>
    <artifactId>jetty-ee10-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>12.0.10</version>
    <configuration>
        <testClassesDirectory>${project.basedir}/target/resources</testClassesDirectory>
        <!--                            <useTestClasspath>true</useTestClasspath>-->
        <!--                            <webAppXml>${project.build.outputDirectory}/jetty-web.xml</webAppXml>-->
        <useTestScope>true</useTestScope>
        <contextXml>${project.build.outputDirectory}/jetty-web.xml</contextXml>
        <httpConnector>
            <port>15600</port>
        </httpConnector>
    </configuration>
</plugin>

Here is the jetty-web.xml:
<?xml version="1.0"  encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE Configure PUBLIC "-//Jetty//Configure//EN" "http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/configure.dtd">

<Configure class="org.eclipse.jetty.ee10.webapp.WebAppContext">

    <Set name="contextPath">/${deployable.artifactId}</Set>

    <Set name="war">
        <SystemProperty name="config.home" default="."/>/webapps/${deployable.artifactId}-${project.version}.war
    </Set>

    <!--Allow log4j & other properties to be loaded outside of the WAR depending on environment-->
    <Set name="extraClasspath">
        <SystemProperty name="config.home" default="."/>/resources/${deployable.artifactId}
    </Set>
    
</Configure>

How ever it works if used org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-maven-plugin version 11.0.14 or with the updated plugin but removing the set extraClasspath property from the xml file. Did the extraClasspath property changed in version 12 or usage of it? I haven't been able found anything.

What is your system property "config.home" set to?  as the default of "." is just bogus.

It isn't set in my dev machine. As you've mention it i've tried it just now and it works if i set it to an existing directory but fails for non existing directories. I've tried with the 11.0.14 version also, it doesn't fail when set to a non exsisting directory but it doesn't auto create it either it just ignores i think. So from my understanding i must set a valid path with the newer version.

Correct, non-existing directories are invalid.  Things have changed a ton with regards to how URL / URLClassLoader works in Java (lots of deprecations, tons of changes in operation, etc)

Jetty 11 is EOL, and we have reports of URL / URLClassLoader behavior differences when using JDK 17 LTS, and JDK 21 LTS due to the URL changes in the JDK itself (when using Jetty 11 or older versions with the new JDKs).

Thank you for your response. This resolves my problem.

As @Joakim Erdfelt pointed out in the comment, the new version fails when extraClasspath set to a non-existing path contrary to the older version.
